# How to mock Cache::remember in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, mockery

Within a unit test method, I tried to mock a `Cache::remember` response like this:

```
Cache::shouldReceive('remember')
    ->once()
    ->with('my_key', 120, function() {}) // There are 3 args in remember method
    ->andReturn([]);
```

But I get this error:

> exception 'Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException' 
>       with message 'No matching handler found for 
>       Mockery_0_Illuminate_Cache_CacheManager::remember
>       ("my_key", 120, object(Closure)). Either the method was
>       unexpected or its arguments matched no expected argument 
>       list for this method

I don't understand why I got this error and did not found anything in Laravel documentation about this. It says there is no matching, but it seems to match.

How can I mock a `Cache::remember` response?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

replace 3rd argument of `with` method to `\Closure::class` to matching any closures.

```
Cache::shouldReceive('remember')
    ->once()
    ->with('my_key', 120, \Closure::class)
    ->andReturn([]);
```

Comment: What is Closure::class... when we use this.

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi
`Closure` is basically a type of any function, regardless of it's parameters or return values, that has no name ie. an anonymous function (`function (...) {...}`), or an anonymous arrow function (`fn (...) => ...`), but not a named function/method (`function iHaveAName(...) {...}`). The way OP put in the third argument, the `shouldReceive` method expects this exact function (not just the same), so you use `Closure::class` instead, to indicate the third argument must be some anonymous function, which includes whatever function is actually passed to `shouldReceive`.

Answer (score -1):

See this issue about challenges with mocking the Cache facade -

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10803

also reference

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9729